# Add Shadow DOM to Chrome Extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I am new on the chrome extension. I developed a chrome extension with React and used components from https://mantine.dev . When I complete my extension, I tested on different sites, and saw that the css of the extension changes on different sites. I learnt that, the style is inherited from the original sites and solution is using shadow DOM. I want to convert my extension with enabled shadow DOM. I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-shadow-root on my root component but my whole css has broken in that case. So, how to add shadow DOM to my finished chrome extension on react?
Thanks.